# CGlib-wired bean is recreated each time its method is invoked

Tags: java, spring, inversion-of-control, cglib

I'm observing some strange behavior with prototype-scoped class-proxied Spring beans. I'm using Spring 4.1.2.

I'm creating a single bean manually, then I invoke its method 3 times. On each method invocation a new class instance gets created - the code below prints a new ID. This means I cannot reliably store the state inside the bean.

**Expected**:
Single instance of the class.

**Observed**:
Each bean method invocation leads to new class instance creation.

I've dug into CGlib - it acquires the target Spring bean from the bean factory for each method invocation. The Spring bean factory happily creates a new bean each time (since it is a prototype bean).

**Is this the expected behavior or a bug?**

```
@Component
@Scope(value = ConfigurableBeanFactory.SCOPE_PROTOTYPE, proxyMode = ScopedProxyMode.TARGET_CLASS)
public class BeanClass1 extends SomeAbstractClass implements I1, I2 {
     public void tellMe() {
        System.out.println(this);
    }
}

BeanClass1 bean = beanFactory.getBean(BeanClass1.class);
bean.tellMe();
bean.tellMe();
bean.tellMe();
```

Comment: Well that is the point of a scoped proxy... You want a thread or request scoped object not a prototype scoped one in this case.

Comment: I actually want this: once _manually_ created, the bean is not "recreated" behind the scenes. 

I've switched to JDK proxies - they work as expected (be me, at least). Still, I had to promote the class-only methods to interfaces to be able to use them. This part I don't like, though.

Answer (score 0):

I've switched to JDK proxies, they do not recreate beans on each bean method call.

The bean is now annotated with

```
@Component
@Scope(value = ConfigurableBeanFactory.SCOPE_PROTOTYPE)
```